# Update Item Flow fails when list is being edited by a user (Status 400): how can I retry until it works?

Tags: power-automate, http-400-bad-request

I have a flow that updates a SharePoint list item if certain changes have been made to that item. My list has a number of flows running on it, but it has users working in it at the same time, so while this flow usually succeeds, sometimes I get an error:

> Save Conflict.
>
> Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user. If
> you want your changes to be applied, click Back in your Web browser,
> refresh the page, and resubmit your changes.

If my update item block fails due to this error I'd like to get it to wait a bit and retry until it works (when the live user is no longer editing that list item). It seems like "configure run after" can be used to help address this, but I've had trouble nailing down how... not sure if it's the settings for the update item block or the apply to each container that it's in, and if I need to rerun the full flow in case of an error or if I can just retry the discrete update item block. Can anyone help me with the specifics?

The trigger is when an item is modified, using the trigger conditions to only run if the modified item has had the Status changed to Verified:

[image]

Then I initialize a bunch of variables and a compose function that aren't related to the issue I'm having (so, not pictured).

Next I do a lookup (Get Items) in another reference list in SharePoint to get the email address for the school related to my modified list item. That generates an Apply to Each container, and within that, I update my original list item that was recently modified:

[image]

That Update Item block (along with the Apply to Each container) is the one that's sometimes failing because someone is editing the list item:

[image]
[image]

So, how can I get the Update Item action to try again until the list item is available and can be updated successfully?

Comment: Maybe this might help? https://ashiqf.com/tag/retry-after-failures-in-power-automate/

Comment: While it's not quite as easy to follow, it looks like that's a similar solution to the one marked as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I handle this type of thing is:

1. Initialize Boolean variable. Value = `true`
2. Add a `Do Until` action. Condition = `variable is equal to false`
3. Inside the Do Until, add your `Update Item` action
4. After the update item, add a `Delay` action and configure it to `run after the Update item action fails`
5. After the Delay action, add a `Set Variable` action that updates your variable to `false`. Configure it to `run after the Delay action is skipped`.

   [image]

   [image]

   [image]

Comment: Thank you - this explains perfectly how to put the solution in place. I've updated one of my problem flows with this, re-run the failed ones and so far it's working flawlessly.

Comment: Follow-up: I can confirm now that I've put this on a couple of flows and they've had time to run - I can see examples now where the flow failed the first time, looped once, and completed successfully. Perfect - thanks!